How to set up URL forwarding in nginx ubuntu?
Current env is ubuntu server 20, nginx installed.
Now what I want to achieve is
http://192.168.1.5/c1234 --> http://192.168.1.5:8081/web
http://192.168.1.5/c5678 --> http://192.168.1.5:8082/web
port info is stored in a csv file , like
c1234=8081
c5678=8082

is it possible to use grep to get that port ?
What keyword I should search? Proxy or forwarding or rewrite? Any web link is welcomed.
Thank You

Nginx Reverse Proxy would help with this.
This setup allows you to redirect incoming requests from Nginx to backend servers based on the path.
location ~ ^/c1234(.*)$ {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8081/web$1;
}

location ~ ^/c5678(.*)$ {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8082/web$1;
}


The ~ ^/c1234(.*)$ is a regular expression matching the path
that starts with /c1234

proxy_pass is the directive to redirect the traffic.

Just change the 127.0.0.1 IP address to the needed IP address.


Test the configuration and reload NGINX
sudo nginx -t
sudo systemctl reload nginx

You should be able to achieve
http://192.168.1.5/c1234 --> http://192.168.1.5:8081/web

http://192.168.1.5/c5678 --> http://192.168.1.5:8082/web

To learn more about it, see the next documentation:
https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/web-server/reverse-proxy/

Thank you. If that port info is stored in a file, it is possible to use linux grep to get that port ?  the original post edited

I mean, you could do that, by running a python script or a shell script or something like that to read de CSV file, because NGINX configurations are static, so to be able to achieve that you should run the code every time the configuration changes, and as far as I know NGINX doesn't support commands like grep

Thanks, I think I got your points. use shell script to read csv first and then generate that NGINX configuration.
